# How to delete the subfolders and files inside the subfolders, but not deleting the root files in nodejs

Tags: node.js

consider I have a folder

Parent

- one.json
- two.json
- folder1
  -- one.java
  -- two.java
- folder2
  -- three.java

Now, I need to delete the folder1 and folder 2, but should not delete one.json and two.json. Basically all the files in the root should exist nd all folders and its contents should get deleted. How we can do it in nodejs. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the path to the parent directory (ie the one containing `one.json`, `two.json` and `folder1` and `folder2`) is `/path/to/parent`. Furthermore I assume you are familiar with the promises api of the node `fs/promises` module

Then you can use [`readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreaddirpath-options) to get all entries of your parent directory

```
import { readdir } from 'node:fs/promises';
let entries = await readdir('/path/to/parent', { withFileTypes: true });
```

Setting `withFileTypes` to `true` will return a list of of [`fs.Dirent`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#class-fsdirent) objects. Then you can iterate over that list of entries, and whenever one of them is a directory (ie `entry.isDirectory()` returns `true`) you delete this directory using [`fs.rmdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesrmdirpath-options) and leave all other entries untouched

```
import { rmdir } from 'node:fs/promises';
import { join } from 'path';

for (let entry of entries) {
  if (!entry.isDirectory())
    continue;

  await rmdir(join(entry.parentPath, entry.name), { recursive: true });
}
```

Using `recursive: true` with `rmdir` will delete all elements in the specified directory and finally the directory itself. If you don't specify `recursive: true`, you can only remove empty directories.